# Set Icon at the end pf textfield Flutter

Tags: button, flutter, dart, textfield

I need a FormField which contains both suffixIcon and Ordinary icon in a single row.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the three ways to add icons to your textfield

```
TextField(
  controller: ...,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(...), //Icon outside
    prefixIcon: Icon(...), //Icon at the beginning
    suffixIcon: Icon(...), //Icon at the end
  ),
),
```

Comment: I just need a icon after ```suffixIcon```.
The icon which is printing before textfield right, that i need after textfield that's it

Comment: @Santhosh you can use any `Widget` you want as all the icon properties inside `InputDecoration` takes any `Widget`. you can use `Row` as you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row and add icon anywhere you want.

```
Container(
    child: Row(
    children: <widget>[
        Icon(),
        Icon(),
        Expanded(child: TextField()),
        Icon(),
        Icon(), 
    ]),
),
```